# RedirectToAction As Get Request format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an action result that I want to redirect to an action with a dynamic ID.

```
  return RedirectToAction("Engine", new {id = latestVersion.Id});
```

However, the URL that returns ends up being:

```
domain.com/project/engine/xxx
```

what I need however is it to be:

```
domain.com/project/engine?id=xxx
```

Here are my current maproutes:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "PrevSession", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, id2 = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Is there a way to change the way this is formatted at the controller level?

Comment: Not at the controller level.  Controllers do not have control over urls.  You'll need to provide all the RouteMaps you have (which do control urls).

Comment: Why? You use MVC magic to parse the id parameter in your routes, and `RedirectToAction` makes use of them.

Comment: @devio, I have a lot of javascript that cries if there is that extra / in there for the id

Comment: remove your first route or the name of the parameter on your action method.

Comment: and btw, you can call this with either URL pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1.**

you can change the `id` route param to some other name like,

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{myId}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", myId = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

and change accordingly in the controllers(where they are used), or

**Option 2.**

You can add a dummy route definition without `id` parameter like,

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "RouteWithoutId", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}" 
            );
```

and use `RedirectToRoute` method like,

```
return RedirectToRoute("RouteWithoutId", new { action = "Engine", id = latestVersion.Id});
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer

```
     routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: Yeah but now you broke the `/controller/action/id` route for all other action methods using that route (non-attributed). That means that bookmarked links or static links (non `@Html.ActionLink()`-generated ones) no longer work.

Comment: Yes true, which I personally don't use in the application, but if there is an answer that addresses both situations I'll accept it!