# How to RedirectToAction in asp.net-core when I use [HttpGet("public-profile/{avatarName}")]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My problem is that I've added a new route `[HttpGet("public-profile/{avatarName}")]` in `PublicProfile` action and I don't know how to redirect to this Action.

So this is the Action that I want get redirected

```
 [HttpGet("public-profile/{avatarName}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PublicProfile(string avatarName)
    {
      return View();
    }
```

What I had try was this way

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PublicProfle()
{
        return RedirectToAction("PublicProfile", "name");
}
```

However it isn't working

I've read about it here but it doesn't help me
[RedirectToAction As Get Request format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119959/redirecttoaction-as-get-request-format) 
[RedirectToAction with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter) 
[ASP.Net Core MVC RedirectToAction is appending controller name in front of returnUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280717/asp-net-core-mvc-redirecttoaction-is-appending-controller-name-in-front-of-retur)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
return RedirectToAction("PublicProfile", new { avatarName = "name" });
```